# Background service killed after receiving broadcast

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver which receives download completed `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` from Android's `DownloadManager` class. The broadcast receiver is defined in the XML as following:

```
<receiver android:name=".DownloadReceiver" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Every thing works well if I keep the activity running. However, if the activity is not running while the service is running in background, it causes the background server to be killed every time `DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` broadcast comes in.

The broadcastreceiver is:

```
public class DownloadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // it will cause MyService to be killed even with an empty implementation!
   }
}
```

The service is:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onBind called");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.w(TAG, "onCreate called");

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Log.w(TAG, "onStartCommand called");

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        Log.w(TAG, "onDestroy called");
    }
}
```

The Activity starts the service:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            startService();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    return true;
}

public void startService() {
    Intent start = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
    startService(start);
}

public void stopService() {
    Intent stop = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
    stopService(stop);
}
}
```

Any idea why the service got killed by the broadcast when activity is not running?

Thanks!!

Comment: why r u creating new intent for same class

Comment: why you are creating twice object for intent...just use first one to start and stop the service.

Comment: @CobraAjgar Using different Intent to start and stop the service is not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From where do you make the call to `stopService()`?

If you are making the call in your `Activity`'s `onPause()`, `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` then your `Service` is stopped every time you leave your `Activity` or when the `Activity` gets destroyed by the system.

I don't see any connection between the `BroadcastReceiver` or the system broadcast and your `Service` from the code you posted.

Comment: The service is a foreground service and it keeps running even the activity is closed. stopService() is only called from a button click event. Activity's onPause(), onStop() or onDestroy() doesn't affect the service. And yes, DownloadReceiver is not connected to MyService at all. MyService doesn't handle any Broadcast. I updated my original question with the activity class now.